# How to place OneDrive on network share

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I need to place my OneDrive folder on a network drive. Tried symlinks, doesn't work. Any other tricks to try?

Comment: Have you tried logging out of the OneDrive application, signing back in, and selecting a different directory that's on a network share? You may need to map the share as a drive, I can't recall for certain.

Comment: @JW0914 I did. Can't be placed in that folder... Tried symlinking, same result. I maybe got an idea - setting OneDrive to a local folder. Then  quitting OD, replacing the folder with Symlink.

Comment: From search results, it doesn't appear possible, as [this](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-onedrive-network-drive) is the closest I found

Comment: Other than [this](https://www.comtech-networking.com/blog/item/404-how-to-map-onedrive-as-a-network-drive-to-see-all-your-files/), I found nothing.